# Encryption in javascript frontend (browser env)

Tags: javascript, encryption, frontend, aes

I am trying to encrypt my password in the frontend (javascript)before I send it to the backend (fastapi, python)
Although many Google searches said crypto can be used, I saw that it works only in the nodejs environment and not in the browser environment

Is there anyway I can achieve encryption in my js frontend so that decryption can be done in the backend?

I see some articles on crypto-js which requires me to install it separately, but apparently we do not have permission to use cryptojs so that had to be ruled out.

Tried using crypto but that did not seem to work

Comment: Not crypto-js but just `crypto` or `window.crypto` which is the same thing. You know, like how `console.log` and `window.console.log` are the same thing?

Comment: `crypto` is a browser feature and was not originally a node.js feature though newer versions of node does ship with `crypto`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto for documentation of the browser API. Specifically you want the object returned by `crypto.subtle`

Comment: What’s the threat model that’s prompting you to use reversible encryption on just a password between your frontend and backend? Do you have TLS?

Comment: And of course: what makes you think encrypting a string in JS in the browser _improves_ security? (because security through obscurity is not security, it's just pretending to be security). What does using a secure protocol not already do that you think you're adding with this?

Answer (score 3):

Use https, problem solved.

The magic in encryption is not the encryption itself, but trusting that you encrypt *for the expected receiver*. In-browser-encryption can not add any more trust in using the right key than what https provides: the server would need to provide its public key and you have no way to trust it to be the correct key.

Not what you wanted to hear, but that time/work is better spent where it makes a difference.

Answer (score -3):

You can use Web Cryptography API.

Evidently people on this board are not generally aware of the fact that secure curves using `subtle` is implemented in browsers. See [Secure Curves in the Web Cryptography API](https://blogs.igalia.com/jfernandez/2023/06/20/secure-curves-in-the-web-cryptography-api/) and [Secure Curves in WebCrypto](https://github.com/WICG/webcrypto-secure-curves/blob/main/explainer.md) for usage.

You can use the same code in the browser by substituting writing and reading files with `<input type="file">`, `<a>` element or other options such as WICG File System Access API for reading and writing files locally, and/or use `fetch()`, `WebTransport`, WebRTC Data Channels, Web Torrent or other means to send and receive encrypted and decrypted signals over the network.

The below JavaScript run in Chromium 124 generates private and public keys, exports to `"jwk"` format, signs some arbitrary data using the private key, then imports the keys as `JSON`, and verifies the data signed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head> </head>

  <body>
    <h1>
      Web Cryptography API - Generate, export, import private and publick keys
    </h1>
    <button id="generate-keys">Generate, export</button>
    <button id="import-keys">Import</button>
    <script type="module">
      const generateKeys = document.querySelector("[id='generate-keys']");
      const importKeys = document.querySelector("[id='import-keys']");
      const algorithm = { name: 'Ed25519' };
      const encoder = new TextEncoder();
      const decoder = new TextDecoder();
      // Some message to be signed.
      const data = encoder.encode('Some message');
      let privateKey, publicKey, signature, verified;
      generateKeys.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
        try {
          const cryptoKey = await crypto.subtle.generateKey(
            algorithm,
            true /* extractable */,
            ['sign', 'verify']
          );
          // Export public and private keys as JSON
          privateKey = JSON.stringify(
            await crypto.subtle.exportKey('jwk', cryptoKey.privateKey)
          );
          publicKey = JSON.stringify(
            await crypto.subtle.exportKey('jwk', cryptoKey.publicKey)
          );

          // Pass a string or an object with only the name property, as above.

          signature = await crypto.subtle.sign(
            algorithm.name,
            cryptoKey.privateKey,
            data
          );

          console.log(privateKey, publicKey, signature);
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
          console.trace();
        }
      });
      importKeys.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
        try {
          // https://github.com/tQsW/webcrypto-curve25519/blob/master/explainer.md
          const cryptoKey = {
            privateKey: await crypto.subtle.importKey(
              'jwk',
              JSON.parse(privateKey),
              algorithm.name,
              true,
              ['sign']
            ),
            publicKey: await crypto.subtle.importKey(
              'jwk',
              JSON.parse(publicKey),
              algorithm.name,
              true,
              ['verify']
            ),
          };

          verified = await crypto.subtle.verify(
            algorithm.name,
            cryptoKey.publicKey,
            signature,
            data
          );

          console.log(cryptoKey, verified);
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
          console.trace();
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have  generated, exported, and imported using the same code in `node`, `deno`, and `bun`, and in the browser.

Make sure you understand `node:crypto` is not Web Cryptography API, it's Node.js' internal implementation that cannot be polyfilled. To access `webcrypto` in `node`, `deno`, and `bun`, use something like `import {webcrypto} from node:crypto`.

Comment: OP asked for frontend, this is NodeJS, this is not an answer.

Comment: _"OP asked for frontend, this is NodeJS, this is not an answer."_ That Web Cryptography API code is used in `node`, `deno`, `bun`, and in the browser - the frontend.

Comment: Yes, but `fs` is not available in the browser. This is pointless regardless, since the solution is to just use HTTPS and then it's handled automatically.

Comment: It is available in the browser [Secure Curves in the Web Cryptography API](https://blogs.igalia.com/jfernandez/2023/06/20/secure-curves-in-the-web-cryptography-api/). You obviously have not run the code in the browser. OP doesn't ask about HTTPS. OP asks about encrypting data in the browser.

Comment: @M.O. I updated the answer to include an example of generating, signing, exporting, and import private and public keys entirely in the browser. Tested on Chromium 124.

Comment: I mean, the code will run, but if you're not using HTTPS, how are you going to share that private key securely with the backend? And if you're using HTTPS, the connection is already encrypted, and this would give no extra security.

Comment: Nowhere does OP talk about "security". Nor do I in my answer. There really is no such thing as "security" for any signal communications. I answered the question with code that works as expected in the browser. What OP or anybody else does with the code is their business. OP talsk about encrypting a password.